# React Component Order of Mounting/Loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does React always load the components from top to bottom by default?
For example if I have this

```
class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
        <First />
        <Second />
        <Third />
        <Fourth />
      </div>

    )

  }
}
```

Will the sequence of mounting by default be always
First, Second, Third, Fourth ....from top to bottom like shown above???

Comment: Yes - It will be rendered in the that you described

Answer (score 0):

-Yes, React does use top to bottom approach.This approach is useful when react creates virtualDOM and updates it's own DOM.

-have look to this https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html